# Embedded debezium doesnt capture changes

Tags: spring-boot, debezium

Im running an embedded Debezium (1.2.0) in a Spring application, but it only captures changes when starting up

My setup looks like this:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("name", "engine");
props.setProperty("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector");
props.setProperty("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore");
props.setProperty("offset.storage.file.filename", "/tmp/offsets.dat");
props.setProperty("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000");
/* begin connector properties */
props.setProperty("database.hostname", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.port", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.user", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.password", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.server.id", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.server.name", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.dbname", "xxxx");
props.setProperty("database.history", "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory");
props.setProperty("database.history.file.filename", "~logs/dbhistory.dat");
props.setProperty("snapshot.lock.timeout.ms", "-1");

try (DebeziumEngine<ChangeEvent<String, String>> engine = DebeziumEngine.create(Json.class)
            .using(props)
            .notifying(this::handleEvent)
            .build()) {
            // Run the engine asynchronously ...
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executor.execute(engine);

            // Do something else or wait for a signal or an event
  
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to start debezium " + e);
        }

private void handleEvent(ChangeEvent<String, String> changeEvent) {
    logger.info(changeEvent.toString());
}
```

When i boot the application it captures the latest changes, but ends with

```
INFO  i.d.p.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator - Finished streaming
INFO  i.d.p.m.StreamingChangeEventSourceMetrics - Connected metrics set to 'false'
```

Then no subsequently changes are captured until next application restart

No errors are thrown

Answer (score 0):

you must not leave the `try` block as this would close the engine and stop the streaming. So in place of the comment `// Do something else or wait for a signal or an event` must be somewaiting logic or you should not place `engine` into `try` with resources for automated sopping.